# Отобразить последние 10 записей массива

Tags: массивы, php

Как Отобразить только последние 10 записей массива ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например [вот так](http://ideone.com/SRwkNR), только надо еще проверку сделать: если длинна массива >= 10, то юзаем такой метод, иначе нет. Может кто-то вариант поинтереснее предложит =)

используйте [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 4):

10 последних независимо от длины массива

```
array_slice($array, -10, 10);
```

Comment: чего вы его минусуете? У него самое правильное решение

Comment: чем оно от вашего отличается ?

Comment: потому что не надо языковыми средствами реализовывать логику, которая уже есть в языке ;)

Comment: @eicto, во-во, у меня лишняя функция count($input) =)

Answer (score 2):

- проверить больше ли длина массива за 10
- если да, то for($i = длина - 10; ...
- если нет вывести весь массив

Без знания логики нет программирования.